# Inserting Rows in MySQL in Go very slow?

Tags: mysql, go

So I have been rewriting an old PHP system to Go looking for some performance gains but I'm not get any. And the problem seems to be in the Inserts i'm doing into Mysql.

So where PHP does some processing of a CSV file, does some hashing and inserts around 10k rows in MySQL it takes 40 seconds (unoptimized code).

Now Go on the other hand stripped away of any processing and just the same inserting of 10k(empty) rows takes 110 seconds.

Both tests are run on the same machine and I'm using the go-mysql-driver.

Now for some Go code:

This is extremely dumbed down code and this still takes almost 2 minutes, compared to PHP which does it in less then half.

```
db := GetDbCon()
defer db.Close()

stmt, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO ticket ( event_id, entry_id, column_headers, column_data, hash, salt ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )")

for i := 0; i < 10000; i++{
    //CreateTicket(columns, line, storedEvent)
    StoreTicket(models.Ticket{int64(0), storedEvent.Id, int64(i),
                    "", "", "", "", int64(0), int64(0)}, *stmt)
}

//Extra functions
func StoreTicket(ticket models.Ticket, stmt sql.Stmt){
    stmt.Exec(ticket.EventId, ticket.EntryId, ticket.ColumnHeaders, ticket.ColumnData, ticket.Hash, ticket.Salt)
}

func GetDbCon() (sql.DB) {
    db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "bla:bla@/bla")

    return *db
}
```

[Profiler result](http://min.us/l6pL9DsLSvTdz)

So is it my code, the go-mysql-driver or is this normal and is PHP just really fast in inserting records?

==EDIT==

As per requested, I have recorded both PHP and Go runs with tcpdump:
The files:

- [Go Tcpdump](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1920297/golang10000.tcpdump)
- [Go Textdump](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1920297/golangRESULT.txt)
- [PHP Tcpdump](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1920297/php10000.tcpdump)
- [PHP Textdump](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1920297/phpRESULT.txt)

I have a hard time reaching any conclusions comparing the two logs, both seem to be sending the same size packets back and forth. But with Go(~110) mysql seems to almost take twice as long to process the request then with PHP(~44), also Go seems to wait slightly longer before sending a new request again(the difference is minimal though).

Comment: Same machine is fine, but is it the same database and table? have you defined any extra indexes? Just a wild guess.

Comment: They operate on different databases with minor differences in naming(structure is identical), the indexes are exactly the same though and the databases are truncated before each test.

Comment: What Go version and MySQL driver are you using?

Comment: go1.1.2 linux/amd and the latest go-mysql-driver files from github

Comment: Turn on MySQL statement outputting to log files.  Run and compare insert statement outputs with the PHP version and the Go version.

Comment: I suggest running strace on your program to collect the sql timings independent of go (or dtruss on mac, not sure on windows). Also it may depend on where you are running the code. Are both go and php running from the same machine to same db?

Comment: I wouldn't start with strace/dtruss, but with a network capture program, such as tcpdump/tshark/wireshark. Looking at the profiler result, I see that 1. the numbers are fairly small, maybe you should profile a longer run or with a smaller alarm time, 2. there is a box on the lower left corner (futex) that implies a lot of time is spent waiting for the results from Mysql.

Comment: Again, with a network capture program, it would be interesting to compare the actual protocol packets sent by PHP and by the Go Mysql driver when they issue the `stmt.Exec`. PHP might be setting some protocol flag that tells Mysql to discard any results and just return an OK/Error value, reducing the waiting time between one insert and the other.

Comment: Finally, although it's not an answer to your question, you might want to try Mysql's multiple-row insert statement (`insert into ... values (row1), (row2)...`) and find the best number of rows per statement by benchmark. You could also issue several statements in parallel using goroutines, if the insert order does not matter to your application.

Comment: I originally tried the multiple row insert that Tobia suggested, but I had better luck with LOAD DATA INFILE, especially if you're already working with a csv file that can be easily parsed. My file is basically records separated by new line with columns separated by commas and it runs pretty quickly. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html for more information on how this works.

Comment: @Verran Mind sharing your time results for the multiple-row inserts? Are you getting equally "slow" results then?

Comment: Are you using the same database engine in both databases?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`  Should show `Engine=InnoDB` (for example) in the output.  If they are different that may be the cause of timing differences.

Answer (score 4):

It's an old question but still - better late than never; you're in for a treat:

put all your data into a `bytes.Buffer` as tab-separated, newline terminated and unquoted lines (if the text causes problems, it has to be escaped first). NULL has to be encoded as `\N`.

Use http://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#RegisterReaderHandler and register a function returning that buffer under "instream". Next, call  `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "Reader::instream" INTO TABLE ...` - that's a very fast way to pump data into MySQL (I measured about 19 MB/sec with Go from a file piped from stdin compared to 18 MB/sec for the MySQL command line client when uploading data from stdin).

As far as I know, that very driver is the only way to LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE without the need of a file.

Answer (score 3):

I notice you're not using a transaction, if you're a using a vanilla mysql 5.x with InnoDB this will be a huge performance drag as it will auto-commit on every insert.

```
func GetDbCon() (sql.DB) {
    db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "bla:bla@/bla")
    return *db
}

func PrepareTx(db *db.DB,qry string) (tx *db.Tx, s *db.Stmt, e error) {
 if tx,e=db.Begin(); e!=nil {
  return
 }

 if s, e = tx.Prepare(qry);e!=nil {
  tx.Close()
 }
 return
}


db := GetDbCon()
defer db.Close()

qry := "INSERT INTO ticket ( event_id, entry_id, column_headers, column_data, hash, salt ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )"

tx,stmt,e:=PrepareTx(db,qry)
if e!=nil {
 panic(e)
}

defer tx.Rollback()
for i := 0; i < 10000; i++{
 ticket:=models.Ticket{int64(0), storedEvent.Id, int64(i),"", "", "", "", int64(0), int64(0)}
 stmt.Exec(ticket.EventId, ticket.EntryId, ticket.ColumnHeaders, ticket.ColumnData, ticket.Hash, ticket.Salt)

 // To avoid huge transactions
 if i % 1000 == 0 {
  if e:=tx.Commit();e!=nil {
   panic(e)
  } else {
   // can only commit once per transaction
   tx,stmt,e=PrepareTx(db,qry)
   if e!=nil {
    panic(e)
   }
  }
 }
}

// Handle left overs - should also check it isn't already committed
if e:=tx.Commit();e!=nil {
 panic(e)
}
```